# Remove Object from Array When Matching Properties are Found

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I want to remove any objects from my array that have a matching `start` and `end` property in reverse order.

```
const arr = [
  { start: 'Nebraska', end: 'Kentucky' },
  { start: 'Montana', end: 'New York' },
  { start: 'Wyoming', end: 'California' },
  { start: 'California', end: 'Wyoming' },
  { start: 'New Hampshire', end: 'Ohio' },
]
```

i.e., if these two objects exist in the array

```
{ start: 'Wyoming', end: 'California' },
{ start: 'California', end: 'Wyoming' }
```

I want to remove

```
{ start: 'California', end: 'Wyoming' }
```

I feel like `reduce` is the way to go for this solution, but not quite sure how to implement it. Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that checks whether the accumulator contains an item where the `end` property is equal to the current value's `start` property and the `start` property is equal to the current value's `end` property with the use of [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const arr=[{start:"Nebraska",end:"Kentucky"},{start:"Montana",end:"New York"},{start:"Wyoming",end:"California"},{start:"California",end:"Wyoming"},{start:"New Hampshire",end:"Ohio"}];

const result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (!a.find(e => e.end == b.start && e.start == b.end)) a.push(b);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

If you wish to overwrite when an item is found with the same `end` property as the `start` property and vice versa,  you can instead use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index and [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the item at that index:

```js
const arr=[{start:"Nebraska",end:"Kentucky"},{start:"Montana",end:"New York"},{start:"Wyoming",end:"California"},{start:"California",end:"Wyoming"},{start:"New Hampshire",end:"Ohio"}];

const result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  let index = a.findIndex(e => e.end == b.start && e.start == b.end)
  if (index != -1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
  }
  a.push(b);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple array filter do the trick:

```js
const arr = 
  [ { start: 'Nebraska',      end: 'Kentucky'   } 
  , { start: 'Montana',       end: 'New York'   } 
  , { start: 'Wyoming',       end: 'California' } 
  , { start: 'California',    end: 'Wyoming'    } 
  , { start: 'New Hampshire', end: 'Ohio'       } 
  ] 

const arr2 = arr.filter((c,i,a)=>
  {
  let n = a.findIndex(x=>x.start===c.end && x.end===c.start)
  return n<0 || n>i
  })
 
 console.log( arr2 )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

You can also make it one-liner

```
arr.filter(({ start, end }) => map.get(end) === start ? false : map.set(start, end))
```

```js
const arr = [
  { start: "Nebraska", end: "Kentucky" },
  { start: "Montana", end: "New York" },
  { start: "Wyoming", end: "California" },
  { start: "California", end: "Wyoming" },
  { start: "New Hampshire", end: "Ohio" },
];

const map = new Map();
const result = arr.filter(({ start, end }) => {
  if (!(map.get(end) === start)) {
    map.set(start, end);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive this kind of filtering by following this simple approach :

1. declare a variable `set` contains values of combination of `end start`
2. filter to get only ones `start end` that are not in the array of set `end start`.

```js
let set = [];
const result = arr.filter(({ start, end }) => {
    if(!set.includes(start+end)){
        set.push(end+start);
        return true;
    }
  return false;
});
console.log(result);
```